# Form Submit Empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form here that I'm trying to get an error message when either 3 boxes are empty when I click submit but it's not working, what am I doing wrong? I put in a `onsubmit` in my form but still doesnt work

HTML:

```js
var message = document.getElementById("ErrorMessage");
    
function clearMyField(el) {
  if(el.placeholder !='') {
    el.placeholder = '';
  }
}
    

function checkforblank() {
  var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
  for(let i = 0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
    let v = allInputs[i].value.trim();
    let n = allInputs[i].name;
    if(v == ""){
      message.textContent = n + " is empty";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Lab 6 - Task 2 </title>
  <style>
  span {
padding-left: 10px;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 20%;
}
button { margin-left: 10px; }
body {
width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
border: 1px solid black;
}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="task2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
    <h1> Form Submit </h1>
    <p> <span>Name:</span> <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
    <p> <span>Student Id:</span> <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="StudentID" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
    <p> <span>Email:</span> <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
    <p>
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
    <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> &nbsp;</p>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Button type should be "submit" instead of button for the submit to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the button should be `submit` instead of `button`. Since you are comparing the *value* inside the function, you have to set the input's *placeholder* property instead of *value*

```
<button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
```

```js
var message = document.getElementById("ErrorMessage");

function clearMyField(el) {
  if(el.placeholder !='') {
    el.placeholder = '';
  }
}


function checkforblank() {
  var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
  for(let i = 0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
    let v = allInputs[i].value.trim();
    let n = allInputs[i].name;
    if(v == ""){
      message.textContent = n + " is empty";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
button { margin-left: 10px; }
body {
  width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
  <h1> Form Submit </h1>
  <p> <span>Name:</span> <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
  <p> <span>Student Id:</span> <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="StudentID" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
  <p> <span>Email:</span> <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
  <p>
  <button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
  <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> &nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Though I will prefer the following:

```js
var message = document.getElementById("ErrorMessage");

function clearMyField(el) {
  if(el.placeholder !='') {
    el.placeholder = '';
  }
}


function checkforblank() {
  var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
  for(let i = 0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
    let v = allInputs[i].value.trim();
    let n = allInputs[i].name;
    if(v == ""){
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
button { margin-left: 10px; }
body {
  width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
  <h1> Form Submit </h1>
  <p> <span>Name:</span> <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" onfocus="clearMyField(this);" required></p>
  <p> <span>Student Id:</span> <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="StudentID" onfocus="clearMyField(this);" required></p>
  <p> <span>Email:</span> <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" onfocus="clearMyField(this);" required></p>
  <p>
  <button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: So I added in the button type but say for example if I have any of the fields missing, it still doesnt display any error message saying its missing

Comment: so I edited it with what you provided so it would give error message on either or if a field was left blank, its not giving me any errors now if its blank on either field, am I doing it right? I've edited it in original

Comment: @ahlie94, no, your current code will not do that.....since you are checking only the name filed and filling message only for that......I will suggest you to use the default `required` attribute instead....I am also curious to know whether the answer  does work or not as that gained already some votes....

Comment: @ahlie94, I have updated for all the inputs...notice the the changes in the HTML.......please check the updated answer......

Comment: kind of strange, when I run your code here it works fine but when I run it on Atom, the error messages still don't play

Comment: @ahlie94, then the issue might be somewhere else in your code.....by the what is the error saying?

Comment: there is no error, it just resets all the field forms, I'll edit original post what I have

Comment: @ahlie94, I have added the executable code snippet with all the code in your question and it is working as expected.....

Comment: I'll try on another computer if anything but say if instance i just wanted it to say if one field is missing only as a general statement rather a specific field, how would that be done?

Comment: @ahlie94, you can check that in the condition like....`if(allInputs[i].id != "input2" && v == ""){`

Comment: @ahlie94, thanks for accepting the answer. One thing, as now the question an answer looks similar, may I request you to update the question with the previous code...so that it will be easier for the future reader to understand what the problem is and how the solution is made......thanks

Answer (score 4):

Fix this:

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="checkforblank()">
</form>
```

[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

There is no need for return statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use html5 attributes to do this easily. (required, placeholder attributes)

Try below code.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Lab 6 - Task 2 </title>
      <style>
        span {
          padding-left: 10px;
          display: block;
          float: left;
          width: 20%;
        }
        button { margin-left: 10px; }
        body {
          width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
      </style>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="get">
          <h1> Form Submit </h1>
          <p><span>Name:</span> <input id="input1" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" required></p>
          <p><span>Student Id:</span> <input id="input2" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="StudentID" required></p>
          <p><span>Email:</span> <input id="input3" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" required></p>
          <p>
            <button id="submitButton" type="submit">Submit </button>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
          </p>
          <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> &nbsp; </p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the error messages because the form submission refreshes the page. To see the errors, use **event.preventDefault** to get the errors.
Try the below code.

```
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <title> Lab 6 - Task 2 </title>
            <style>
                span {
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    width: 20%;
                }
                button { margin-left: 10px; }
                body {
                    width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>
            <form id="myForm" method="get">
                <h1> Form Submit </h1>
                <p> <span>Name:</span> <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
                <p> <span>Student Id:</span> <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="StudentID" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
                <p> <span>Email:</span> <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" onfocus="clearMyField(this);"></p>
                <p>
                    <button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </p>
                <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> &nbsp;</p>
            </form>

            <script>
                var message = document.getElementById("ErrorMessage");
                //document.getElementById('myForm')

                function clearMyField(el) {
                    if (el.placeholder != '') {
                        el.placeholder = '';
                    }
                }

                //Add event listener
                document.getElementById('myForm')
                    .addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                        console.log('submit')
                        //prevent the default submission to see the errors.
                        e.preventDefault()
                        var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
                        for (let i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
                            let v = allInputs[i].value.trim();
                            let n = allInputs[i].name;
                            if (v == "") {
                                message.textContent = n + " is empty";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
            </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```